# Kotlin Moshi adapter return null when library throw JsonDataException

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

We are using old backend. Sometimes list of objects is returned when contract says it should be text (and other ways).

How/where can we handle **JsonDataException Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT** so we can remove object with null value for wrong parsed data?

```
{
...
   "data":{
      "value1":"example",
      "value2":2,
      "value3":"example",
      "value4":"example"
   },
   "other_data":"example",
   "data2":"only string"
}
```

```
{
...
   "data":"", //how to ignore this part -> set null?
   "other_data":"example",
   "data2":{ //how to ignore this part?
      "value":2
   }
}
```

Should this be handled in adapter, if yes is there a need to parse all json manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a Moshi adapter for this. You'll just need to peek ahead, see if it's the value you expect, and skip the value if it's not.

Here's a generalized adapter in Kotlin.

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
internal annotation class SpecifiedTypeOrNull(val token: JsonReader.Token) {
  class Adapter(
    private val delegate: JsonAdapter<Any?>,
    private val token: JsonReader.Token
  ) : JsonAdapter<Any?>() {
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Any? {
      if (reader.peek() != token) {
        reader.skipValue()
        return null
      }
      return delegate.fromJson(reader)
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Any?) {
      delegate.toJson(writer, value)
    }

    class Factory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
      override fun create(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Set<Annotation>,
        moshi: Moshi
      ): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        if (annotations.isEmpty()) {
          return null
        }
        var token: JsonReader.Token? = null
        var nextAnnotations: MutableSet<Annotation>? = null
        for (annotation in annotations) {
          if (annotation is SpecifiedTypeOrNull) {
            token = annotation.token
            nextAnnotations = annotations.toMutableSet()
            nextAnnotations -= annotation
          }
        }
        if (token == null) {
          return null
        }
        val delegate = moshi.nextAdapter<Any?>(this, type, nextAnnotations!!)
        return Adapter(delegate, token)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how you can use it for your above code.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Foo(
  @SpecifiedTypeOrNull(JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_OBJECT) val data: Data?,
  val other_data: String,
  @SpecifiedTypeOrNull(JsonReader.Token.STRING) val data2: String?
) {
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
  data class Data(val value1: String)
}

val encoded1 = """
  {
     "data":{
        "value1":"example",
        "value2":2,
        "value3":"example",
        "value4":"example"
     },
     "other_data":"example",
     "data2":"only string"
  }
"""

val encoded2 = """
  {
     "data":"",
     "other_data":"example",
     "data2":{
        "value":2
     }
  }
"""

fun main() {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(SpecifiedTypeOrNull.Adapter.Factory())
    .build()
  val adapter = moshi.adapter(Foo::class.java)
  val decoded1 = adapter.fromJson(encoded1)
  val decoded2 = adapter.fromJson(encoded2)
  println(decoded1)
  println(decoded2)
}
```